# VideoDetector.start throws exception "Failed to initialize, invalid data folder"

Tags: c#, windows, affdex-sdk, emotion

VideoDetector throws below exception when calling `Detector.start()` method.

> Failed to initialize, invalid data folder

My classifierPath is set correctly to `C:\Program Files\Affectiva\AffdexSDK\data`

Am I missing something?

Code:

```
private static string classifierPath = @"C:\Program Files\Affectiva\AffdexSDK\data";
VideoDetector detector = new VideoDetector();
detector.setClassifierPath(classifierPath);
var processor = new AffectivaProcessor(ref AffectivaResult, ref stopProcessing, detectExpressions, detectEmotions, detectEmojis, detectAppearance);

detectorHandler = new AffectivaDetectorHandler(processor);
detector.setFaceListener(processor);
detector.setImageListener(processor);
detector.setProcessStatusListener(processor);

detector.setDetectAllExpressions(detectExpressions);
detector.setDetectAllEmotions(detectEmotions);
detector.setDetectAllEmojis(detectEmojis);
detector.setDetectAllAppearances(detectAppearance);

detector.start();
detector.process(videoFilePath);
detectorHandler.WaitTillProcessing();
detector.stop();
```

Comment: There are files and subfolders in `C:\Program Files\Affectiva\AffdexSDK\data`?

Comment: yes.. there are

Comment: @swargujrania Is this fixed? If not which release are you using?

Comment: @UmangMukeshMehta - No.. it still persists. I am using 9.12.16